# Translations does not work with .pot file

Tags: multi-language, translation

I've created a theme at underscores.me and it seems it is multi-language ready.

There is a `.pot` file in the language folder, so I downloaded POEdit and translated the things in there (like `Posted on`, `Edit`, `1 Comment`, `x Comments` and so on)

Are the above posted words not from the theme but from Wordpress? If so, why it is in English although I have a German Wordpress installed (Backend is in German)?

So I saved it and also as a `.mo` file and uploaded both files on my server into the languages folder. But the translations are not working

Comment: How did you name the files

Comment: mythemename.pot
mythemename.mo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When naming your `po` and `mo` files in a theme, you need to only make use of the language code to name these files. Any other convention will not work

For example, my blog is in Afrikaans and the localization language code is `af_AF`. My `mo` and `po` files are named accordingly, ie, `af_AF.po` and `af_AF.mo`

I'm not sure what the codes are for German, but change the filenames accordingly